# CArdinal incompatible type error DelphiXE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I don't really understand this 'incompatible types' error (Delphi XE2)

```
function TWaveBase.GetHandle: THandle;
begin
  if HandleNeeded then begin
    if HandleAllocated then
      CloseHandle;
    CreateHandle(False);
  end;
  FHandleNeeded:=False;
  Result:=FHandle;
end;
```

[...]

`property Handle:Cardinal read GetHandle;` -> error here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`THandle` is a type declared based on `Cardinal` in Delphi XE. (Because of 64-bit and cross-platform, it's defined as `NativeUInt` in XE2). It's a new type.

If your `GetHandle` getter is returning a `THandle`, your property should also be declared as a `THandle`. Change it and things should work fine.

Comment: So (related to DelphiXE2) i made the change for NativeUInt. I have now this impasse, another incompatible error types Integer and AntiveInt related with MMSystem WaveInClose. -> WaveInClose method returns system.cardinal

Comment: @volvox: This is caused by the same type of error, so the fix would be the same - change one of the types to be compatible with the other. Use the XE2 types when possible, because they'll work XPlatform and in 64-bit, as I mentioned above. (And my answer was to make the change to `THandle`, not `NativeUInt`, if you'll read it more carefully; this keeps it compatible both backwards and going forward.)

Comment: Thanks - i finally took the project under Delphi 2007 - cause too many library not up to date to deal with.

Comment: i feel ur pain. i am converting ~ 100 Mb of sources 2006->XE2 :-)
And some components like ToolBar97 and pascal HTMLViewer and dead long ago.